# jquery not getting hidden field data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, razor

Im sending over some json data and assigning to a hidden field using:

```
@Html.Hidden("hidden-places", @Model.Places)
```

inside my javascript i am doing the following to retrieve the data:

```
  var places = $('#hidden-places').val();
```

however it just comes back as undefined.

i am using this for google maps...

i tried something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      places = $('#hidden-places').val();

    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

but no luck.

Comment: does a hidden input field with an id of hidden-places exist in your DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had multiple elements with the same id on the page causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ID selector:

```
places = $('#hidden-places').val();
```

Note that `#`.

Comment: what does the *generated* html look like then?

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
$('hidden-places').val();
```

...you're looking for the value of a `<hidden-places>` element. Probably not what you mean. You likely want the value of a field with the ID `hidden-places`:

```
$('#hidden-places').val();
```

Comment: Just to be clear: is `hidden-places` an element, a class, or an ID?

Answer (score 0):

"hidden-places" will be the ID of the field and what your jQuery is looking for is going to be an HTML element called hidden-places.

You should use

```
$('#hidden-places').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

did you check if you set a prefix in your viewdata?

how is the element in DOM? checked the value and id?

maybe your element is like

```
<input id="prefix_hidden-places" name="prefix.hidden-places" type="hidden" value="10" />
```